# Factory is undefined despite console.log

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, ionic-framework, factory

I really don't know what it is, and I'm getting desperate why the factory despite is injected and console logged... is undefined after calling a function.
I'm on an Ionic project, so...

Heres my factory:

```
angular.module('starter.services')
.factory( 'EditarBsnsFct', ['$http', function($http){
  var editarBsns = {};

  editarBsns.editarBsns = function(url,datos){
    $http.post(url, datos)
          .success(function(data, status){
            return data;
          });
  }

  return editarBsns;

}]);
```

and my controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers')

.controller('BsnsDashboardEditarCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'EditarBsnsFct', function($scope, $http, $state, EditarBsnsFct){
  $scope.bsns = {};
  $scope.bsns.tags = [];
  $scope.placeholder = 'Etiqueta tu negocio (cheve, rock, dj...)';

  var usuario = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('user') );

  $scope.loadTags = function($query){

    return $http.get('http://hoppers.dev/getTags', {cache:true})
                .then( function( res ){
                  var tags = res.data.data;
                  return tags.filter(function(tag) {
                    return tag.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) != -1;
                  });
                });
  }

  $scope.actualizar = function(){
    var url = 'http://hoppers.dev/dashBsns/actualizar/' + usuario.id;
    var datos = JSON.stringify($scope.bsns);

    EditarBsnFct.editarBsns(url, datos)
                    .success( function(){
                       $state.go('dashNegocio.perfil');
                    })
                    .error( function( err ){
                      alert('error');
                    });

  }

}])
```

So when I click actualizar function in my view, it gives me the error:

> ReferenceError: EditarBsnFct is not defined
>       at Scope.$scope.actualizar (http://localhost:8100/js/Controllers/bsnsDashboardEditarCtrl.js:26:5)
>       at fn (eval at  (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15),
>   :4:221)
>       at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57514:9
>       at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24673:28)
>       at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24772:23)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57513:13)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12098:21)
>       at triggerMouseEvent (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2865:7)
>       at tapClick (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2854:3)
>       at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2927:5)

I don't know what it is, so hope somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

You are injecting EditarBsn**s**Fct (notice the s) but trying to reference it as EditarBsnFct

Comment: well the error goes away... but now is getting... Cannot read property of undefined...

Comment: Read the stack trace and the message of the error. If you're stuck, then accept this answer, then ask *another* question with the fixed code and the new error and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

As your factory is defined in a module that is different than your controller module.

When defining your controller module, you need to inject your factory module as a dependency that helps the controller identify your factory that is defined in another module.

something like :

```
angular.module('starter.controller',['starter.services'])
```

Comment: the services are injected in the main app, because the code structure is separating the views, controllers, services..etc. I have to define a mainModule for each one...so this already included...